# PostgreSQL: What is faster delete by unindexed column or other table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-delete

In our PostgreSQL database, we have a table with around 1TB of data. The table consists of an *id, name, value* and a *timestamp*. The data isn't sorted, and we don't have an index over the timestamp. However, we want to delete everything `WHERE timestamp < '2018-09-01 00:00'`.

We also have a second table with an exact copy of the data we want to delete. The copy process took us around 300 Minutes.

So I wonder which one would be faster. Deleting using the WHERE-clause or using the ids of the other table? If the second one would be more quickly how to write the query?

Comment: How big is the percentage that you want to delete? If that is a substantial part of the table, creating a new table with the data you want to **keep** (`create table to_keep as select ...` - then renaming the table) is probably faster than deleting big chunks of data from the real table

Comment: We want to delete around 170,000,000 rows out of 13,300,000,000 so it's approx 1% this time. However, we will move more and more data in the future. (From this host to another one). At which percentage would be your solution more sufficient? Apart from not having enough disk space left right now.

Comment: If you delete about 1%, then creating a new table won't be faster. That typically starts to be faster at something in the neighborhood of 10% or so. But that depends **heavily** on the table structure, the number of indexes and the hardware speed - it could be less or it could be more. A delete using a JOIN against the second table through the PK of the primary table might indeed be the faster option in this case.

Comment: If this is a process (sounds like TTL) that is going to happen periodically, please consider using time-based partitioning so that you can just `DROP` a complete partition. A regular `DELETE` will also result in quite some work for `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`.

Comment: If you are cleaning out old data on a regular basis you might want to consider partitioning your data (e.g. by year, half year or quarter), then getting rid of the data is a matter of dropping the corresponding partition which should be a sub-second operation

Comment: I know I am advocating it a lot but from my experience it really pays off having a deeper look at automatic partitioning extensions such as [timescaledb](https://docs.timescale.com/).

Comment: Thank you @Ancoron for the hint using automatic extensions. In the future, I will have a deeper look into this. A couple of bad decisions have led us to this situation. I agree with both of you partitioning the data in the first place would have been a good idea. But I expect us to do this 5 times more and than we are done. So I'll guess using one of the 2 mentioned options would be the easiest.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the copying process hasn't created an index for the smaller table, but I'll guess this isn't a problem for deleting using this table. Right?

Comment: Well, with an index it would at least be able to know when to stop searching for more rows to delete. So it would not have to go over all rows using the sequential scan. If the _"copy process"_ also wrote rows chronological then using an index would be way faster and also not involve a lot of random I/O. You can execute the next run with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and get the internal details. Then we could see much better what the biggest bottleneck will be for the remaining 4 runs (and a learning for your next big table maintenance).